# Rails search using Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Guys I'm trying to to find all my users with the business column equal to false. The business column is in another model, so I have 2 models User model and Information Model. I'm trying to use Arel to create my own search. Here is the method on my User Model:

```
def self.search
        users = self.arel_table

        information = Information.arel_table

        users.
            join(information).on(users[:id].eq(information[:user_id])).
            where(information[:business].eq(false))
end
```

I don't see the error, but I getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index

Showing
/Users/jeanosorio/rails_projects/rutalaboral/app/views/users/index.html.erb
where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for `#<Arel::SelectManager:0x007ffcff1c2e20>`
```

here is my action from the users controller

```
def index
   @users = User.search()
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason that you're trying to use Arel instead of ActiveRecord?  In ActiveRecord, you would do the following:

```
User.joins(:information).where(Information.arel_table[:business].eq(false))
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, the reason is that I don't know how to do this in ActiveRecord and a friend told me that I have to use arel :S

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  No, you should definitely be able to use ActiveRecord for this.  Generally, you can do most things with ActiveRecord, dropping down to Arel to do more complicated queries.

Comment: Got it,...I'll try to read more about how to do this with ActiveRecord. Thanks again